# JSON_VALUE in SQL-server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, json

I am looking for an equivalent functionalities of JSON_VALUE in SQL Server 2014. Can any of you post an alternate of the below code which is supported in SQL Server 2014

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(ERROR_MSG, '$[0].applicationName') AS APPLICATION_NAME
FROM tablename
```

It errors out as below when run SQL 2014

> 'JSON_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the accepted answer to the question [How to make JSON from SQL query in MS SQL 2014(https://stackoverflow.com/q/39883243/1820861) over on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is `JSON_VALUE`from another server (PosgreSQL, MySQL...)? You should make that clear and also make clear what functionality it is, exactly, you want. Set up a db fiddle, some sample data and the result you want (using the alternative server if you like) and there are people here who will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

JSON support was not introduced until SQL Server 2016, so you'll need to use custom functions. Check out [Phil Factor's article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/) on this where he provides some code for parsing JSON in earlier versions of SQL Server.